# wave hand & lock phone automatically

Tags: security, lock-screens

Is there any way to lock my Samsung Quattro (running Android 4.2) just by waving my hand upon it?

Comment: Guys, "How do I do X?" is not an off-topic subject. "How do I do X? Is there some app?" is not off-topic either. If you don't like the word "app", just leave it on the side of your plate.

Comment: You could use automation apps like Tasker to use proximity sensor to do this. But the problem will be that it will get locked/unlocked at unwanted situations (like while in bag or pocket).

Comment: Rule of thumb: if "is there an app for" can be re-phrased to "is there any way to (achieve this)", it's most likely on-topic. I just did so with this question.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot promise that any of these solutions work on your device, but there are several apps listed which seem to be able to achieve this, as e.g. [Air Gesture Control](http://www.appbrain.com/app/air-gesture-control/in.tank.corp.proximity) or [Wave Control](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wave-control/com.MarksThinkTank.WaveControl). Just try a [search for "air gestures"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=air%20gestures) on Play Apps.

<sup>**Note:** my links go to *AppBrain*, as that site is not limited to 16 search results. Being an alternative front-end to *Google Play*, you still can install your findings from the latter. *AppBrain* even offers *Google Play* links for each app.</sup>